# Perl Reg Ex Expression - Extract patterns and text after them

Tags: regex, perl, sas

I am working in SAS and have been trying to figure out a perl reg ex that will correctly work with this string
(where src is the string and txt is the lines I would like...and there may be any number of output lines)

```
src='01/04/2017 03:45:32 Some Comment - abc 05/04/2017 16:32:41 Some other Comment 06/07 at something'
txt='01/04/2017 03:45:32 Some Comment - abc'
txt='05/04/2017 16:32:41 Some other Comment 06/07 at something'
```

Below is the SAS code I was using to try and attempt this...

```
data _null_;
  ExpressionID = PRXPARSE('/(\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}) (\s) (\d{2}\:\d{2}\:\d{2}) /xio');
  text = '01/04/2017 03:45:32 Some Comment - abc 05/04/2017 16:32:41 Some other Comment 06/07 at something';

  start = 1;
  stop = length(text);

  /* Use PRXNEXT to find the first instance of the pattern, */
  /* then use DO WHILE to find all further instances.       */
  /* PRXNEXT changes the start parameter so that searching  */
  /* begins again after the last match.                     */

  call prxnext(ExpressionID, start, stop, text, position, length);      
     do while (position > 0);
        found = substr(text, position, length);
        put found= position= length=;
        call prxnext(ExpressionID, start, stop, text, position, length);
     end;
run;
```

Comment: Not really sure this is a `perl` question at all. I'd suggest this isn't a job for a 'magic regex' and rather you're looking at some equivalent of `split`.

Comment: [`.+?(?=$|(?:\d{2}\/){2}\d{4}\s*\d{2}(?::\d{2}){2})`](https://regex101.com/r/Ts05tl/1) ?

Comment: It is a regex, basically I need a regex to identify the start/end of the string.

Comment: What do you want to do if the comment itself contains a date time string in the same format?

Comment: Lazy repetition factor & positive lookahead that Gurman suggests is the best solution IMO. His assumption of `text` starting with a datetime is easy to check if needed.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a variation that focuses on the much simpler pattern that looks for only the 'landmark' `mm/dd/yyyy` within the text.  The prxnext loop tracks the prior landmark and extracts `found` based on that.

```
data extracts(keep=line found);
  if _n_ = 1 then do;
    rxid = PRXPARSE('/\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4} /');  * nominally mm/dd/yyyy followed by at least one space;
    retain rxid;
  end;

  line = _n_;

  infile cards _infile_=text;
  input;

  start = 1;
  stop = length(text);
  position = 0;
  length = 0;

  /* Use PRXNEXT to find the first instance of the pattern, */
  /* then use DO WHILE to find all further instances.       */
  /* PRXNEXT changes the start parameter so that searching  */
  /* begins again after the last match.                     */

  call prxnext(rxid, start, stop, text, position, length);

  lastpos = 0;
  do while (position > 0);
    if lastpos then do; 
      length found $200;
      found = substr(text,lastpos,position-lastpos);
      put found=;
      output;
    end;
    lastpos = position;

    call prxnext(rxid, start, stop, text, position, length);
  end;

  if lastpos then do;
    found = substr(text,lastpos);
    put found=;
    output;
  end;

datalines4;
01/04/2017 03:45:32 Some Comment - abc 05/04/2017 16:32:41 Some other Comment 06/07 at something
Some fakery 01/04 /2017 03:45:32 /11/11/1967. yo 01/02/1102 Some Comment - abc 05/04/2017 16:32:41 Some other Comment 06/07 at something

aabbccdd
01/02/1903 abc def
01/02/1903 abc def sas does have trouble matching a patterns having a trailing space 02/03/1904
;;;;
run;
```

A simpler pattern is sensible when dealing with SAS code that will be around a long time.